# Program is freezed while using Random.nextInt to much?

Tags: java, loops, random, freeze

Is there any chance that program may be freezing by using Random.nextInt() to much?

My program is like:

```
class CustomizedAction extends AbstractAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        clearEverything();

        //Make a new Random instance
        Random rnd = new Random();

        //There is a loop that runs 6 times, 
        //for each time I will processing the value generated by rnd.nextInt() 
        for(loop 6 times) {
             anArrayList = process(rnd.nextInt(), rnd.nextInt());
        }

        //Then I have another loop which runs for 12 times.
        //For each time, I generated a number and do some comparing the 
        //new born with the previous generated numbers 
        //to try to make the numbers from list2 different with list1.

        for(loop 12 times) {
             int aNumber = rnd.nextInt();
             while(anArrayList.contains(aNumber)) {
                  aNumber = rnd.nextInt();
             }
             anotherArrayList.add(aNumber);
        } 
    }
}
```

Sometime, the customizedAction works, but sometime, the customizedAction makes whole program freezing and all previous messages in Console which are printed out before are lost. So strange for me, because if there is something wrong with logic part, the printed messages in Console should not be lost.

The more times I run the loop, the higher chance customizedAction makes program freezing.

So, I'm wondering, does running nextInt() too much can make program freeze?

Here are the images of my program when it's freezing.

1st time try CustomizedAction. Everything is fine.
[image: 1st time try to CustomizedAction]

2nd time try CustomizedAction. The messages printed before in Console are lost and program is freezing. 
[image: 2nd time try to CustomizedAction]

Comment: It always means the same thing in this situation: you're stomping on the Swing event thread. If you have code that needs to be repeatedly called, use a Swing Timer. If you have long-running code, then use a SwingWorker. But most important, **search first** before asking as this sort of question is asked too many times for yet another post, one asked without showing evidence of prior research (sorry to be blunt -- but where's your mention of these threading issues?).

Comment: Hmm, I dont know it's related to Thread or not, because this snippet is for generating the arraylist contains edges and vertices which have different values. Then, if the generation part is done, then swing is called for repaint. If it's related to Thread, if the calculation time is done, then program should be not freezy. But my program is like freezing forever...

Comment: I can **absolutely guarantee** that it is related to thread. You're calling long-running code on the Swing event thread, and the solution is not to do this, to call it on a background thread.

Comment: `while(!anArrayList.contains(aNumber))` are you sure about the not(!)?

Comment: Ah, it contains no ! operator. Thanks, let me edit it. But this is just pseudo code. My actual code returns the correct result. The problem is it's freezing sometime...